# What does this line of Cucumber and Capybara code do?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

I'm brand new to Cucumber and Capybara and I'm having trouble understanding what this one line of code in my homework does. "rating" is a movie rating (G, PG-13, etc.) that is searched for in a table of movies in this context:

```
assert page.has_xpath?('//td', :text => "#{rating}")
```

Could someone explain what every part of this line does?

Comment: It's worth noting that `:text => "#{rating}"` could be written as `:text => rating` and be more obvious. :-)

Answer (score 3):

It checks whether the page contains an element matching the XPath `//td`, that has a text node `"#{rating}"`. If it doesn't, it fails the test.

The XPath `//td` matches every `td` element regardless of its location in the document (because of the double slash).

Here are links to the documentation:

[`assert`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/test/unit/rdoc/Test/Unit/Assertions.html#method-i-assert)

[`has_xpath?`](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Matchers#has_xpath%3F-instance_method)

Answer (score 0):

If any element named `td` has the contents of the given rating, it succeeds.